# Matplotlib plt.text() fails to iterate over loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

While trying to loop over equations on matplotlib, I only get the last text from `plt.text()`. How can I iterate over matplotlib figures and annotate equation for each plot? Also the `plt.savefig()` function does not save the figures.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\GISN21\Ex_04\data5\data3_4.txt',sep="\t",header=0)
df2=df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Station']

def calculate_pvalues(df):
    df = df.dropna()._get_numeric_data()
    dfcols = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    pvalues = dfcols.transpose().join(dfcols, how='outer')
    for r in df.columns:
        for c in df.columns:
            pvalues[r][c] = round(pearsonr(df[r], df[c])[1], 8)
            if pvalues[r][c] < 0.05:
                i=0
                if r != c:
                    #best fit line
                    (m,b)=np.polyfit(df[r] ,df[c] ,1)
                    equation = 'y = ' + str(round(m,4)) + 'x' ' + ' + str(round(b,4))
                    f = plt.figure()
                    plt.text(0.5,0.5, equation)

                    plt.savefig("correlation{i}.png".format(i=i))
                    ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
                    p = sns.regplot(x=df[r],y=df[c],data=df,ax=ax)

    return pvalues

sns.pairplot(df,kind='scatter')

plt.savefig('correlation.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The call to `plt.text` is inside two `if` statements; are you certain it is being executed more than once?

Comment: The plt.figure() prints fine, but the text doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `plt.text` uses data coordinates, and matplotlib doesn't automatically adjust the limits to include text that is not within the data limits. So unless `(0.5, 0.5)` is within the limits when `plt.text` is called it will not be visible. If this is the case, you can resolve the issue by using axis coordinates. This can be done by supplying the axis transformation to the `transform` keyword, i.e.

```py
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, equation, transform = plt.gca().transAxes)
```

Will place the `Text` instance in the center of the current axes.